# Woocommerce add to cart from url code

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm searching to change the way add to cart from url work in woocommerce.

I need to add attached product at the same time to the cart.

I fix the regular way to add a product to the cart but now I have to modify the add to cart from url and I can't find where this code is in woocommerce plugins.

http://yourproducturl.com/shop/?add-to-cart=%ID%

Comment: What is an attached product?

Comment: Attached product are product that is mandatory needed with the product you just add to cart. So I need to add those product in case people forget yo manually add those.

Comment: Have you considered [Force Sells](https://www.woothemes.com/products/force-sells)?